# I am sick and my nose is not running.Any hack for this to get back to normal?

Tags: personal-care

It is literally 5 in the morning. I am drinking tea and have that mint rub stuff on my nose.I put a towel on my forehead and I feels like the nose just hates me.I can not sleep.I've tried everything. Any hack for getting me out of this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Do an inhalation for a few days, preferably not long before bed. That just means finding a heat proof bowl, boiling a kettleful of water, put the water in the bowl, add whatever you've got that's menthol based (Vick, menthol and eucalyptus, olbas oil, karvol capsules, anything like that) if you have something, don't worry about it if you haven't, get a large towel, put the bowl on a table, sit down with the towel over your head and the bowl to make a sort of tent, lean over the steam coming from the bowl and inhale, preferably through your nose as far as is possible. You'll need some tissues handy...

Sleeping with the window slightly open helps too. If it continues for months, see a doctor, you may have allergic rhinitis or a sinus infection.

Answer (score 1):

My methods:

1. Sleep sitting up - sucks, but I've done it for a while when I was really sick.
2. Use a sinus wash (netti pot - google it).  I do it in the shower since it's gross as fuck when you blow the snot out after using it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consult a doctor, even then we do hacks for this too at home. Attaching one such along with:

You better have Ayurveda coffee:

1. 1 mug coffee (~300 ml)
2. 1 pinch cardamom
3. 1 pinch cinnamon
4. 1 pinch ginger
5. 1 tsp coconut oil / coconut butter / ghee

Add these into your normal coffee making process, have it after the formation of a slight foam. You can have this 2 times a day and take rest with steam methods for removing nasal congestion.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on why your nose is stuffy, certain things may work better than other things.  Here are some things to try:

- If it's not too cold outside, open a window to let some fresh air in.
- Use a humidifier or vaporizer if your room is very dry.  (The noise might help as well.)
- Prop your head up on several pillows and sleep on your back.  You can even prop the bed up if you want by placing boards under the wheels/posts at the head of the bed.
- Try a white noise machine, or a soothing CD or app (something that plays ocean sounds, nature sounds, or other calming noises).  White noise can work wonders for helping you fall asleep, even when you don't feel good.

Answer (score 0):

If you gently sniff some pepper into your nose, your nose will start to burn, but you will be able to unclog your nose much quicker.
I do it anytime I have a cold, and it works pretty well. Hope this will also work for you.